# Facebook Real-Time Updates, Logged Success on Verification, No Pushed Notifications

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook-graph-api

I'm following the process "documented" at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/v2.5 and I have an externally-facing callback URL that handles both the GET request and the POST from facebook.

Initially, we had some issues getting the app subscribed to the page, but it now shows on the Graph API Explorer when we query the subscribed_apps edge.

I have logging set up for every step on our side, and when we set up the webhook, we are getting success for hitting the page, and returning the token they require.  However, when we update the page with a post, we get nothing, nothing logged, as if they didn't even try to send the update.

I am an admin on the page and the app, and have been beating my head against this, so I thought I'd see if anyone here had ran into that issue.

Here's my code (C#/MVC), the first function is the successful Get request:

```
    [UserAccess(SystemRole.Guest)]
    public ActionResult Facebook(hub hub)
    {
        _logger.Log(LogSeverity.Info, "Hit Method Webhooks/Facebook");
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(hub.verify_token))
            {
                Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
                string data = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
                _logger.Log(LogSeverity.Info, data);

                return Content(string.Empty);
            }
            var ourToken = Config.Setting("FacebookVerifyToken");
            if (hub.verify_token == ourToken)
            {
                _logger.Log(LogSeverity.Info, "Success verifying token, returning challenge string.");
                return Content(hub.challenge);
            }
            else {
                _logger.Log(LogSeverity.Info, "Failure verifying token, returning empty string.");
                return Content(string.Empty);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Log(LogSeverity.Info, ex);
        }
        return Content(string.Empty);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [UserAccess(SystemRole.Guest)]
    public ActionResult Facebook()
    {
        _logger.Log(LogSeverity.Info, "Hit Method Webhooks/Facebook POST");

        Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
        string data = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();




        _logger.Log(LogSeverity.Info, data);

        return Content(string.Empty);
    }
```